# Rails, simple number between conditions query in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Fairly easy i guess but somehow the documentation lack this (maybe of its simplicity).

I want to display values from a table with are between a min and a max.

My code is:

```
def something
  @foo = Foo.where( :number => ((params[:min])..(params[:max])) )
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you checked that your params are numbers and not strings?

```
@foo = Foo.where(number: (params[:min].to_i)..(params[:max].to_i))
```

Rails does accept a range

```
# select all where number between 1 and 10
Foo.where number: 1..10

# between 1 and 9
Foo.where number: 1...10
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. It doesn't have to be an int as long as the column is set to be numeric. Numeric string such as params[:min] should work normally.

Comment: True, but he is composing a range. It is a good idea to cast the variable.  ("-1".."10").to_a is very different from (-1..10).to_a

Answer (score 1):

Think of it how you would do the same using SQL. Following should work:

`Foo.where("number>?", params[:min]).where("number<?",params[:max])`

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work, but in these situations I like to add some control to what gets to the database.  Typically, I would write it like this

```
def something
  # Make sure something gets set and is an integer
  min = (params[:min] || 0).to_i
  max = (params[:max] || 10).to_i

  # Do some basic range checking so that the query doesn't return every row in the database
  min = 0 if min < 0
  max = 100 if max > 100

  @foo = Foo.where( :number => (min..max) )
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
end
```

Actually, the extra code I just added should be put in a method on the Foo object to get the data, as this clutters up the controller with code that should be Model code.

Answer (score 1):

find_by_all method:

```
Foo.find_all_by_number(params[:min]..params[:max])
```

or using some SQL

```
Foo.where('id in (?)', params[:min]..params[:max])
```